# Kubernetes: Pod is not created after applying deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a problem with Kubernetes on my local machine. I want to create a pod with a database so I prepared a deployment file with service.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bid-service-db
  labels:
    app: bid-service-db
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "5432"
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    app: bid-service-db
    tier: database

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bid-service-db
  labels:
    app: bid-service-db
    tier: database
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bid-service-db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bid-service-db
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: mydb
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        image: postgres:13
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        name: bid-service-db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: bid-service-db
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-persistance-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: bid-service-db-volume
status: {}
```

I am applying this file with `k apply -f bid-db-deployment.yaml`. `k get all` returns that only service was created, but pod not started. What can I do in this case? How to troubleshoot that?

Comment: What is the output of the apply command? Did you check in all namespaces? `kubectl get deployments -A`

Comment: Yeah, I checked this command, but nothing extraordinary. I just restart the cluster, after that, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

if you didn't get any errors on the 'apply' you can get the failure reason by:

```
kubectl describe deployment/DEPLOMENT_NAME
```

Also, you can take only the deployment part and put it in a separate YAML file and see if you get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Since after restart the cluster it worked for you, a good ideia next times should be verify the logs from kube-api and kube-controller pods using the command:

`kubectl logs pn kube-system <kube-api/controller_pod_name>`

To get the list of your deployments in all name space you can use the command:

`kubectl get deployments -A`